# FFMpeg to manually set a file duration

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

My generated mkv containers (containing h265 video) are missing the video length. Is there a way to set this before the piped input is closed?

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'camera01-20190815-203646.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2048x1536, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
```

Currently files are created using the following command(s). (thanks to [Gyan](https://superuser.com/users/114058/gyan) for helping with this):

```
ffmpeg                              \
    -hide_banner                    \
    -loglevel error                 \
    -nostdin                        \
    -nostats                        \
    -xerror                         \
    -stimeout 5000000               \
    -thread_queue_size 2048         \
    -reorder_queue_size 16000       \
    -rtsp_transport tcp             \
    -i rtsp://xxx                   \
    -c:v copy -an -sn -dn           \
    -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=1 \
    -f hevc -                       \
    |                               \
    ffmpeg                          \
    -hide_banner                    \
    -loglevel info                  \
    -nostats                        \
    -nostdin                        \
    -xerror                         \
    -f hevc                         \
    -i -                            \
    -c copy                         \
    -f segment                      \
        -segment_time 3600          \
        -segment_format matroska    \
        -segment_format_options live=1:reserve_index_space=100k \
    -strftime 1                     \
    "/srv/video/netcams/archive/recordall/camera01-%%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M%%S.mkv"
```

Is there a simple way to either specify the file length during the mkv writing or to have ffmpeg insert it before closing the file segment?

Comment: Add -report to both commands, run till 2-3 segments are created and share those files.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fSlTghwHXEdtlG1XSjNT8zibRWt7Qvk0

Comment: interestingly running ffprobe on the files shows the Duration and start times confused: 

Input #0, matroska,webm, from './camera01-20190819-211618.mkv':
  Metadata:
  Duration: 00:00:33.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 716 kb/s

...
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:33.000000000
Input #0, matroska,webm, from './camera01-20190819-211640.mkv':
  Metadata:
  Duration: 00:01:01.00, start: 33.000000, bitrate: 391 kb/s
```

Answer (score 0):

So getting somewhat closer to a solution now:
`ffmpeg -f hevc -i - -c copy -f segment -segment_time 30 -segment_format matroska -strftime 1 camera01-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.mkv` (removed the reserve_index_space option).

gives duration data to the file. However this is not resetting at the beginning of each segment - instead each segment's duration includes the previous segments' duration.

```
find . -exec  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i {}  -f ffmetadata   \;  > /tmp/out.txt                                                                                 

Input #0, matroska,webm, from './camera01-20190819-212041.mkv':                                                                                                                                                      
  Metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Duration: 00:00:32.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 694 kb/s                                                                                                                                                          
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2048x1536, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:32.000000000

Input #0, matroska,webm, from './camera01-20190819-212102.mkv':                                                                                                                                                      
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 32.000000, bitrate: 401 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2048x1536, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:01:00.000000000


Input #0, matroska,webm, from './camera01-20190819-212130.mkv':                                                                                                                                                      
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:01:32.00, start: 60.000000, bitrate: 287 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2048x1536, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1k tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:01:32.000000000
```

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent of "reset timing data for each file" flag.... or equivalent?

Yes there is. The final command looks like this:

```
    ffmpeg                          \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -hide_banner                    \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -loglevel info                  \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -nostats                        \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -nostdin                        \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -xerror                         \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -f hevc                         \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -i -                            \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -c copy                         \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -f segment                      \                                                                                                                                                                                
        -reset_timestamps 1         \                                                                                                                                                                                
        -segment_time 30            \                                                                                                                                                                                
        -segment_format matroska    \                                                                                                                                                                                
    -strftime 1                     \                                                                                                                                                                                
    "/srv/video/netcams/archive/recordall/camera01-%%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M%%S.mkv"
```

(Still seeing spurious `[segment @ 0x5652b57e1500] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly` warnings which I've never worked out how to remove but at least services that look for a valid duration are now seeing it.